# Use the image as root background and text background

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-label

I have one problem with background in my appication - my text not use root background.
My code:

```py
    from tkinter import *
    import os
    import tkinter.scrolledtext as scrolledtext
    
    DIR1= os.path.abspath(os.curdir) + "/"
    
    root = Tk()
    root.iconbitmap("1.ico")
    root.geometry("600x700+690+100")
    root.title("place() method")
    root.title("Test")
    font = PhotoImage(file=DIR1+'7.png')
    label_1 = Label(root, image=font)
    label_1.place(x=0, y=0)
    label_1 = Label(text="""Hello world""", pady=10, font="Arial 14")
    
    Output = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, height=20,
                  width=60,
                  bg="light cyan",
                  wrap=WORD)
    
    Display_1 = Button(root,
                       height = 2,
                       width = 50,
                       text="Check DIR",
                       command=lambda: check_dir())
    
    label_1.pack()
    Display_1.pack(side=TOP, pady=(10,10))
    Output.pack()
    mainloop()
```

But as result have:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IuvF.png)

How to set for text my image=font background?
I want to have the text over my background.
I tried via option 'compound', but it work only for 'center' position...
Maybe you can help me.

Comment: tkinter widgets does not support transparent background.  You can try using `Canvas`.

Comment: Can you share your background image with us?

Comment: you can use your background image, olny change name and this image must be in the same directory as py file:
font = PhotoImage(file=DIR1+'7.png')

Comment: acw1668 - many thanks
canvas helped